# Inject Logger in controller method when calling with Ajax

Tags: symfony

Here is a method signature in the controller :

```
public function myAction(Request $request, SessionInterface $session, LoggerInterface $logger)
```

This is what I wrote in services.yml :

```
AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Normally, all of the parameters (request, session and logger) are automatically injected.

I call this action of the controller using Ajax but there is a problem for logger (request and session are well injected):

```
    Controller myAction requires that you provide a value for the "$logger" argument
```

This happens for one method only because the ajax calls to some other methods of the controller work perfectly.

The only difference I can see using some debug tools is that the one that does not work has connection : close though the others have connection: keep-alive.

I dont see why it is done differently.

When I erase the LoggerInterface parameter, it works good and connection is keep-alive like the others.

Can you help ?

Symfony 3 platform

```
services:
_defaults:
    # automatically injects dependencies in your services
    autowire: true
    # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    autoconfigure: true
    # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
    # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
    public: false
```

Comment: Have you activated the autoconfigure?

Comment: which means?...

Comment: Check this doc, it can help you https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-service-autoconfiguration

Comment: That would explain why it works for every method but one ?

Comment: it was done already

Comment: Could you show the starting points of your services.yaml file?

Comment: Did you try to inject `LoggerInterface` in the Controller's constructor directly?